# Error on win32_userprofile delete method?

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to create a script that cleans up temporary profiles on a 2008-R2 server.

Weird thing is I'm positive I had this working fine before our holiday, now the script doesn't work after said holiday :(.

The script:

```
 $keys = ls "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\*.bak"
 foreach ($key in $keys){
 $sid = $key.name | select-string -Pattern 'S-\d-\d+-(\d+-){1,14}\d+' | out-string
 $sid = ($sid).Split('\')[6]
 $sid = ($sid).Split('.')[0]
 $profile = get-wmiobject win32_userprofile -computername localhost | where-object {$_.SID -eq $sid}
 $profile.Delete()
 }
```

If I run that, or any form of modification of that delete method, I get:

```
Exception calling "Delete" with "0" argument(s): ""
At C:\temp\remove_temp_profiles.ps1:7 char:18
 ($profile).Delete <<<< ()
     CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
     FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

If I run a:

```
get-wmiobject win32_userprofile | get-member
```

I can see that the delete method is *not* there. It's supposedly "hidden" whatever that means.

Apart from the delete not working, the rest of the script works perfectly (regex is another battle haha!)

I've also instead attempted to use `remove-wmiobject` instead. However it causes errors with:

```
Remove-WmiObject : 
At C:\temp\remove_temp_profiles.ps1:7 char:28
+ $profile | remove-wmiobject <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Remove-WmiObject], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveWmiObject
```

I've spent ages and ages googling and trying different things, and all of the solutions appear to be "use the `$variable.Delete()` and it works fine". I don't know how to program (only basic scripting) so apologies for my newness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be because the profile is still considered to be loaded. You can verify this by looking at the **loaded** property. You should also look at using the `-Filter` parameter instead of piping everything to Where-Object.

```
$keys = ls "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\*.bak"
 foreach ($key in $keys){
     $sid = $key.name | select-string -Pattern 'S-\d-\d+-(\d+-){1,14}\d+' | out-string
     $sid = ($sid).Split('\')[6]
     $sid = ($sid).Split('.')[0]
     $profile = get-wmiobject win32_userprofile -computername localhost -Filter "SID -eq '$sid' AND NOT Loaded='True'"
    $profile.Delete()
 }
```

If you just want to see if profiles are still loaded:

```
Get-WMIObject win32_userprofile -computername localhost -Filter "Loaded='True'" | 
Select SID,LocalPath,Loaded
```

Comment: Hey mate thanks for that I'll give that a test this arvo. Cheers.